# Umbraco hostnames behind a load balancer

Tags: http, https, content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I have two sites that I wish to manage through one Umbraco admin database

https://mysite.company.com
and
https://myothersite.company.com

The Umbraco database sits behind a load balancer.

I've tried setting the hostnames within Umbraco to be https://mysite... and https://myothersite... but both sites are being branded the same and served the same content

I noticed that the request headers (viewed through Chrome Developer tools) are showing simply as mystic.company.com and myothersite.company.com - should THESE be the values I set in the hostnames (`umbracoDomains` table, `domainName` field)

Answer (score 1):

There is [documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/server-setup/load-balancing/) on the Umbraco site specific to setting up Load Balanced sites in Umbraco which you should use for reference.

In terms of adding the hostnames in Umbraco, you can use the user interface to do this without directly modifying the umbracoDomains table. The hostnames you add should match the host headers you assigned to the site through IIS.

- Right-click on the homepage node and select `Culture and Hostnames` add the hostname relevant to the site you have selected then repeat for other sites.